Is emission ceiling lights possible casting shadows?
I'm a former Lightwave 3D user and now using Blender, and learning fast.
My number one issue is the ceiling lights.
Does emission comes with shadows? Is this possible for cycles?
All I'm using emission for lighting on ceilings of offices, I'm creating backrooms realistic and I'm able. But something is abit off I'm just realizing it's not to realistic enough. I've noticed all I'm missing is the real shadows and not a shadow fuz.
Is light linking the answer?
The project title is called Backrooms FANTASIA.
Thank you for helping, your the best.

Added just now images for Cycles 4.2 and EEVEE 4.2
Cycles
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1m1GHuWfWOMi9Gy9cSxPvw2_ALt79ncfF/view?usp=sharing
EEVEE
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1pCKb_AI1kZGdJY8GDOFeSj9NmdxZx2fh/view?usp=drive_link

Are you sure you are using Cycles and not EEVEE? Cycles should create more or less realistic shadows from emissive materials immediately, EEVEE is a bit trickier and maybe needs more adjustments. Screenshots of your scene, the render settings, how the shadows look like in your scene etc. would be helpful instead of just plain text.

I apologize.
Now I noticed Cycles emission shadows, and I misunderstood, the perspective of Blender.
I can now see why Blender is better and easier than octane
